# Sony Vaio FX 112 LCD colours change to pink with lines

Tags: display, sony-vaio

My sony Vaio FX 112 has the problem that its display turns pink when I move the mouse. Then it gets fine but after some time it again turns pink.

A after a week's usage it totally changed to pink.

I got it repaired from Vaio centre for a hefty amount but still the problem arised again. Now the repair person said I changed the cable but still after one day of use it turned pink again.

What can I do against that?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it could be a faulty backlight if its the whole screen- they tend to flicker at random, though the one i have flickers yellow rather than pink

its not something you'd want to fix yourself, and if a problem re-occurred soon after you paid to have it fixed, you might want to bring it back, and yell at them a little